# How can give a specific dictionary, which is in a list, a name?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this function that creates a dictionary for one student

It's been days of me looking over the web and trying things out, but the only change in output that I've made is putting an empty list (without a name) into the json file. A `[]` outputted to the file.

```
    def add_student_to_database(fname, lname, test1, test2, test3):
        fullname= '%s %s' % (fname, lname)
        all_students = []

        def lettergrade(test1,test2,test3):
            overall = ( int(test1+test2+test3) )/3
            if overall >= 93:
                letter = 'A'
            elif overall >= 90:
                letter = 'A-'
            elif overall >= 87:
                letter = 'B+'
            elif overall >= 83:
                letter = 'B'
            elif overall >= 80:
                letter = 'B-'
            elif overall >= 77:
                letter = 'C+'
            elif overall >= 70:
                letter = 'C'
            elif overall >= 60:
                letter = 'D'
            elif overall < 60:
                letter = 'F'
            return letter

        student = {
            "First name": fname,
            "Last name": lname,
            "Test 1": test1,
            "Test 2": test2,
            "Test 3": test3,
            "Grade": lettergrade(test1,test2,test3)
        }
        all_students.append(student)
        with open('students.json','a+')as json_file:
            json.dump(all_students,json_file, indent= 4)
```

I expect to get:

```
'all_students': [
    {'John Doe': 
        'tests':{
            'test 1': 100,
            'test 2': 100,
            'test 3': 100
            }
    {'Will Smith':
        'tests': {}(repeat for a bunch of students)
]
```

Instead, when it does run well, I get

```
{
    'first name': 'John',
    'Last name': 'Doe',
    'Test 1': 100,
    'Test 2': 100,
    'Test 3': 100
}
```

I want to name the list "all_students" and each individual student's dictionary named by the variable `fullname`.
I tried starting all over again with the original code that I had (the one posted here) and its throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./grades.py", line 12, in <module>
    class STUDENTS(object):
  File "./grades.py", line 81, in STUDENTS
    add_student_to_database(fn,ln,t1,t2,t3)
  File "./grades.py", line 54, in add_student_to_database
    "Grade": lettergrade(test1,test2,test3)
NameError: name 'student' is not defined
```

Which I managed to fix but forgot how I did it. So, can you help me with all of this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code (by substituting a print statement for the final two lines) and it outputs what I expected, which is a single dictionary contained within a list.

```
[{'First name': 'Chris', 'Last name': 'Sullivan', 'Test 1': 86, 'Test 2': 99, 'Test 3': 88, 'Grade': 'A-'}]`.
```

Also, I don't think you would want to have the '+' in the call to `open` as I don't think you are going to do anything but append to the file.

Finally I don't think the `all_students` list is going to ever have more than one element as it is initialized every time your run add_student_to_database. To build up the list you would either have to declare it outside the function, build it into a class, or use a callback function.

Here's a class that is hopefully close to what you're after.

```
import json

class all_students():
    def __init__(self):
        """ Set up an empty dictionary to hold the student information, and a
            another dictionary to contain the thresholds for each grade level.
            The keys for the dictionary must be in descending order.
        """
        self.all_students = {}
        self.grades = {93: 'A', 90: 'A-', 87: 'B+', 83: 'B', 77: 'B-', 70: 'C', 60: 'D', 9: 'F'}

    def lettergrade(self, tests):
        """ Returns letter grade when passed a tuple of individual test scores.
            The first argument is a tuple containing the test scores (e.g. (91, 66, 82))
            The average is calculated by dividing the sum of the elements in the
            tuple by the number of elements.
            Then the grades dictionary is searched for the first score which is
            higher than the average. When that is found, the grade is returned.
        """
        overall = int(sum(tests)/len(tests))
        for score, grade in self.grades.items():
            if overall >= score:
                return grade

    def add_student_to_database(self, fname, lname, *tests):
        """ Adds (or replaces) a student grade entry to the all_students dictionary. The new entry
            is represented by a dictionary containing the individual test scores and the letter grade
            The test scores are passed as individual arguments. *tests gathers
            those positional arguments into a tuple, e.g. (91, 66, 82)
            A new dictionary containing the first & last names plus the letter
            grade is added to the all_students dictionary, with the key equal
            to the student's full name.
            Finally, that dictionary is updated with the individual test scores.
            That update uses "Test 1", "Test 2", etc. as the key. The enumerate
            function provides the test number in the same order as it is stored
            in the tuple (Note the use of an f-string to format the key). This
            function will return the index (position) of each element to the 
            variable i, and the value of the test score in variable g. The
            indices start at 0 so we add 1 to start with Test 1, not Test 0.
        """
        fullname = f"{fname} {lname}"
        self.all_students[fullname] = {
                'First name': fname,
                'Last name': lname,
                'Grade': self.lettergrade(tests)
        }
        self.all_students[fullname].update(dict((f'Test {i+1}', g) for i, g in enumerate(tests)))

    def show_students(self):
        """ Prints the names and letter grade for each student. Note the
            use of an f-string to format the output. Also see the use of
            the items() method to return the key/value pairs to the variables
            fullname/grades respectively for each iteration of the for loop.
        """
        for fullname, grades in self.all_students.items():
            print(f"{fullname}: Grade is {grades['Grade']}")

    def write_file(self, fname='students.json'):
        """ Writes student info to json file fname & prints summary 
            This is basically the same as your original.
        """
        with open('students.json','a') as json_file:
            json.dump(self.all_students,json_file, indent= 4)
        self.show_students()

# The following is run as a test when this file is run (e.g. Python programname.py)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    students = all_students()
    students.add_student_to_database('John', 'Doe', 80, 88, 92)
    students.add_student_to_database('John', 'Public', 95, 91, 80)
    students.write_file()
```

It uses a dictionary of dictionaries, with the outer dictionary keyed by the student's full name, and the inner dictionary similar to what you already had. I decided to allow an arbitrary number of test scores. It will work from 1 to n. It should probably check that that the number of test scores is greater than zero, and that all scores fall between 0 and 100. Each call to `add_student_to_database` will overwrite the previous entry for the same student.

Here's the json file it produces.

```
{
    "John Doe": {
        "First name": "John",
        "Last name": "Doe",
        "Grade": "B",
        "Test 1": 80,
        "Test 2": 88,
        "Test 3": 92
    },
    "John Public": {
        "First name": "John",
        "Last name": "Public",
        "Grade": "B+",
        "Test 1": 95,
        "Test 2": 91,
        "Test 3": 80
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thats where Im at right now. But, If there are multiple students in the list, I need to name each dictionary for when I need to access the data for one specific student; also naming the list like I showed above... what code is needed to get to that point?

Comment: Answer updated. Hopefully it is close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much! To me, it seems that you know a lot of python. Can you explain each part of the code? like teach me at least on the content you've provided please?

Comment: I've expanded the doc strings to add some explanation and tried to mention the important Python components that were used that are well documented in the Python 3.7 documentation. Let me know if you need further clarification. The wonderful thing about Python it that the code is far more concise than the explanations of the code!

Comment: Thank you! I'll let you know.

Comment: Also, I believe that by update you meant that if a student with the same name is entered, it will replace the tests and calculate the new lettergrade but, its not doing that.

Comment: I was adding students from the terminal before, now I don't know how go about it with this code.

Comment: See the bottom, the part after `if __name__ == '__main__':`. That shows how it is used. So you could run Python, then import the file (i.e. if it was called marks.py, you would `import marks`). Then instantiate the object as shown `students = all_students()`, then add students and write the file as shown at the bottom. All that can be entered with the interactive console as you've already been doing.

Comment: Ok but at the moment, I'm not trying to run another python file. I was using the ```sys``` library with ```sys.argv[ ]```. Like you said, it takes nth number of tests, how would I take an nth number of arguments and match them to the tests? I'm guessing it could be done with a for loop: ```for argument, test_number in enumerate(args)``` with having the variable ```args= sys.argv[1:]```. I'm I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Side note, I've noticed you're a VP at IDC so you may not have much free time but If its alright with you, can I contact you through Twitter?

Comment: It does not let me message you.